# Objective C place NSString in NSLog

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nslog

Really basic Obj C question:

before you say this is a duplicate I have already checked other answers and that is what I am using to do this with are saying to do it this way.

So I just want to output a NSString to NSLog but I am getting the error expected ")" on the log line.

I am obviously missing somthing really basic.

Here is the code:

```
//
//  HelloWoldOBJ.m
//  Helloworld2


#import "HelloWoldOBJ.h"

@implementation HelloWoldOBJ

    NSString *make = @"porche";

    NSLog(@"%@", make);

@end
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: code in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Awesome thanks I new it was simple thanks

Comment: glad it helps buddy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call your string in `viewDidLoad` and check

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad

 {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSString *make = @"porche";

NSLog(@"%@", make);


 }
```

you get the out put like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
NSLog(@"%@", make);
```

The above line must be written inside a method, and that method must be called from somewhere. **In short NSLog is not a property**, so it can't be just declared like a property. That's why you are getting this error.